# 必要 and 必要性 usages

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between 必要 and 必要性 and in what situation should I use which

Comment: I can understand the down votes (no research shown), but this does seem like a reasonable question. I looked at Weblio and kotobank and couldn't figure out a difference between 必要性 and 必要 when used as a noun, i,e, when they mean 'necessity'.

Comment: @user3856370 I normally use 必要 only as a noun, but I chanced across 必要性 when reading a novel. Jisho tells me they are the same when used as a noun, so I'd thought I'd ask

Comment: Searching both in ALC and comparing example sentences would likely be a fast way to build an intuition here.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thanks. Never heard of ALC, what is it? Is it アルク?

Comment: Yep. Also known as 英辞郎。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, 必要 is primarily a **na-adjective** rather than a noun. It means "necessary".

- ✅必要な量　❌必要性な量
  necessary amount
- ✅それは必要だ。 ❌それは必要性だ。
  That is necessary.
- ✅必要になった。 ❌必要性になった。
  It became necessary.

If you have *really* used 必要 only as a pure noun, this is the most important difference you have to remember. (And I think this is why your question looked confusing and got downvotes. Your question almost looks to me like "What's the difference between *necessary* and *necessity*?", which is too elementary.)

---

That being said, there *are* some cases where 必要 is used as a noun. In some cases, 必要 and 必要性 are interchangeable, but in some cases, they are not:

- ✅読む必要がある　✅読む必要性がある
- ✅読む必要がない　✅読む必要性がない
- ✅必要に応じて読む　❓必要性に応じて読む
- ✅読む必要を感じる　✅読む必要性を感じる
- ✅必要に駆られる　✅必要性に駆られる
- ❌必要を検討する　✅必要性を検討する
- ❌読む必要が高い　✅読む必要性が高い
- ❌読む必要が乏しい　✅読む必要性が乏しい
- ❌ワクチンの必要について　✅ワクチンの必要性について

It's hard to generalize and I may be wrong, but I feel:

- When the focus is the **degree** of necessity (高い/低い/etc), 必要性 must be used, whereas 必要 and 必要性 are usually interchangeable when the focus is the **existence** of necessity (ある/ない/感じる/etc).
- 必要 follows a verb, but it tends not to be linked to a noun using の.
- 必要性 sounds a little more formal or academic.

Comment: Sounds to me like it's almost always better to use 必要性 rather than 必要 when used as a noun

Comment: @Newbie But it would mean you'll sound unnecessarily formal. I recommend you remember at least 必要{がある/がない/に応じて} as a set phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries say 必要性 means そのものが、どれだけ必要であるかの度合い. That is "the degree of necessity". For example, we can say 日本語を勉強するうえで、この教科書の必要性はとても高い. 必要 can't be replaced with 必要性 in this sentence.